# AngularJS local storage throws exception when setting anything

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I have an AngularJS app, and after logging in and trying to save user data on localStorageService

```
angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule']); ...
function onSuccess(data){...
localStorageService.set('scope', data.data.scope);}
```

it always throws exception. The object is not null, it returns the storage type.

If I call get method, returns null, since, logically does not have anything inside.

Something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you check the localstorage if this variable actually exists. Go to console(F12) -> console tab -> then at the bottom type `localStorage` you can see the contents of the local storage of the browser!

Comment: "it always throws exception." *what is the exception*?  you haven't shown enough here to even begin to reproduce your problem.

Comment: include your code for LocalStorageModule.

Comment: @Claies It always goes to `}).catch (function onError(data){}`  and does not set anything. Other than that, there is really no exception message.

I just started using that library so I don't know if a localStorage object exists. I will @NarenMurali

Comment: @alphapilgrim that would be:
` <script src="components/angular-local-storage.js/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.config(['KeepaliveProvider', 'IdleProvider', function(KeepaliveProvider, IdleProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {});
`
It appears to work up until the point of setting variables.

Comment: your comment just solidifies my point.  In your comment, you suggest that your code is going to a `.catch` block, but there is no `.catch` block in the body of the question.  a `.catch` block is not the same as throwing an exception;  however, without a [mcve] showing ***all the relevant code***, it's virtually impossible to know what you are trying to do, much less why whatever you are trying to do isn't working....

Comment: @Hernán Were you able to see the variable inside the localStorage?

Comment: @NarenMurali it shows this:
`{"isSupported":true,"cookie":{"isSupported":true}}`

I'm in the process to upload a verifiable example to plunker, but that is gonna take a bit.

Comment: It turns out the problem was the complete version of the library, the minified version works ok.

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the non-minified version of the library; the minified one works OK.